# How do I make a batch file replace a sub string within a text file without changing it's layout?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been trying to make a batch file that finds a sub string within a given file without changing the existing layout, syntax, or format of the input file. I have managed to get this script to replace the string that I define, but it **completely** changes the original layout of my document:

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "search=Test incomplete..."
    set "replace=Test successfully completed!"

    set "textFile=Testing document.txt"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
```

Essentially what I want to achieve is a script that can patch a single part of a user-defined text-based file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to use a tool that's like, or is, `sed`, requiring that you use

- [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) or [Windows Services for UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX) (discontinued but if it still runs...) or maybe the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)
- Or just use PowerShell, it's got a sed-like ability in:
  `get-content file.txt | %{$_ -replace "find","replace"}`

<sub>[[Source Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe/127567)]</sub>

Comment: This is good to know, but it must be done in batch as this method is being integrated into an existing batch script. Using another language would require me to completely re-write everything else I have.

Comment: If you pick a standalone `sed` .exe you should be able to call it from within any batch file, just like in a bash script. Just tell it which file and what to find & change it to.

Comment: I've never used bash before. Could I make the PowerShell script, set the batch to call to it _first_ then return to execute the remaining code?

Comment: I think so, I'm not super familiar with powershell, but regular windows batch files are pretty much the same too, runs whatever's on a line then moves onto the next line when it's done. The standalone sed.exe might be easier.

Comment: msys 2.0 is a much better tool than cygwin. It comes with git, sourcetree, and some other tools. In my experience cygwin environment can be easily corrupted due to heavy reliance on Windows registry. Running wsl requires mapping the directory through /mnt/[drive]/... and requires a restart and elevated permissions to install. Thank you for the powershell idea!